# Android ScrollView setOnScrollChangeListener triggers multiple times too fast

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have implemented scroll view and I need to detect the visibility of the view when scrolling and trigger that event once per screen initialization.
But, at random times, I get it triggered multiple times in a very short time (a few ms), and it messes up with my logic in VM.

Is there a way to restrict this triggering and make it trigger once every 100ms or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is something like this right where the trigger happens

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime < 100) 
    return
else {
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // rest of your code
}
```

where `lastTime` is just some variable you keep in your class